# topology Prove or disprove question

Tags: general-topology

1 - Prove or disprove A continuous image of a $T_1$ space is $T_1$.

2 -  Prove or disprove if $X$ is a $T_2$ space, then $\overline{\{x\}} = \{x\}$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Hi Welcome to MSE.  Your question will be received better if you show some effort you have applied.  For example, do you what "continuous", "$T_1$" and "$T_2$" mean?

Comment: @Abdullah Salama: Maybe you should write the question. Also please explain where do you have trouble?

Comment: i want full answer

Comment: @AbdullahSalama Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and the community. Some forms of context include background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc. Moreover, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Let $X$ be $\Bbb R$ in the usual topology (which is $T_1$, and even $T_6$) and $Y= \Bbb R$ in the trivial (indiscrete) topology, which is not even $T_0$. But note that $f(x)=x, X \to Y$ is trivially continuous.
2. If $y \notin \{x\}$ this means that $x \neq y$. Find $U,V$ open and disjoint such that $x \in U, y \in V$. Then $V \cap \{x\} = \emptyset$, so $y \notin \overline{\{x\}}$. This shows that $\overline{\{x\}} = \{x\}$ in any Hausdorff space (and in fact this is equivalent to $T_1$, which is implied by $T_2$).